# Android Kotlin StringRes quantityString

Tags: kotlin, illegalstateexception

Ok so this:

```
fun Context.quantityFromRes(id_: Int, qtt:Int, vararg format: Any) = resources.getQuantityString(id_, qtt, format)
```

xml:

```
<plurals name="header_view">
        <item quantity="one">Oh no! You just lost %1$d Point</item>
        <item quantity="other">Oh no! You just lost %1$d Points</item>
    </plurals>
```

Gives this error:

```
"java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format [Ljava.lang.Object; arguments"
```

Apparent Java fix:

```
public class XmlPluralFormatter {
    private XmlPluralFormatter() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You can't fuck me =(");
    }

    public static String getFormattedString(Context context, int stringRes, int qtt, Object... formatArgs){
        return context.getResources().getQuantityString(stringRes,qtt, formatArgs);
    }

    public static String getFormattedString(Context context, int stringRes, int qtt){
        return context.getResources().getQuantityString(stringRes,qtt);
    }
}
```

- I just realised using this via Java would solve the problem, but i have no idea if there is a Kotlin way of accomplish the same.

PS: Forgot the call:

```
val qtt: Int = 123
context.quantityFromRes(R.plurals.header, qty)
```

I can also do this:

```
fun Context.quantityFromRes(id_: Int, qtt:Int, vararg format: Object) = resources.getQuantityString(id_, qtt, format)
```

but then

```
Required Object, found Int
```

I can also cast:

```
context.quantityFromRes(R.plurals.header, qty, qt as Object)
```

but also gives:

```
"java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format [Ljava.lang.Object; arguments"
```

Also, using code directly without an extension function works:

```
context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.header, qtt, qtt)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is you're passing `format` argument as single parameter instead of spreading it to `Object... args`. The extension method:

```
fun Context.quantityFromRes(id_: Int, qtt:Int, vararg format: Any) = resources.getQuantityString(id_, qtt, format)
```

is equivalent to:

```
fun Context.quantityFromRes(id_: Int, qtt: Int, vararg format: Any): String? {
    val args: Array<out Any> = format
    return resources.getQuantityString(id_, qtt, args)
}
```

Which in Java terms looks like:

```
public static final String quantityFromRes(Context $receiver, int id_, int qtt, Object... format) {
    return $receiver.getResources().getQuantityString(id_, qtt, new Object[]{format});
}
```

What you want to do instead is to use [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

```
fun Context.quantityFromRes(id_: Int, qtt: Int, vararg format: Any): String? {
    return resources.getQuantityString(id_, qtt, *format)
}
```

Comment: Using spread is an elegant solution, thanks for pointing this out